# Built-in "html/template" or "mustache", which one shall I use?

Tags: templates, go, mustache

I'm new to [golang](http://golang.org), and want to use it to build a web app.

I found it has built-in [html/template](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/), which can render html template with specified data, and there is also a [mustache port](https://github.com/hoisie/mustache) which seems good.

I'm not sure which one shall I use. Please give me some advices or comparations between them to let me decide, thank you.

Comment: Take into consideration that `html/template` leaves blank spaces in rendered templates. Much the same as Ruby's ERB. Which is not good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer use html/template because it comes in Go library, and by its simple design.

You can see in the next web application how powerfull it is:

https://bitbucket.org/jzs/sketchground/src

Comment: Be aware that html/template assume that the template is secure.  In other words, don't allow arbitrary users to upload templates for your web app to parse.

Comment: Was hoping for some comparison... :\ I don't consider this to address the original question (even though the OP clearly did).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer html/template. Its simple to use. The codewalk here http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/ can be a start.